# Array over different structs

Tags: c, struct, enums

Say that I have two different structures:

```
typedef struct {
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
 int d;
} struct_1;

typedef struct {
 int a;
 int b;
 int e;
 int f;
 int g;
 int h;
} struct_2;
```

And that they're used in a similar way in two different algorithm. What I would try to do is to substitute both structures, which are basically different types, with a dinamic array, and using two enums for the cases I actually need. The purpose would be to preserve the differents name of the structure fields, instead of using numbers. So something like:

```
typedef enum {
 a,
 b,
 c,
 d,
 num1_fields
} struct_1_fields;

typedef enum {
 a,
 b,
 e,
 f,
 g,
 h
 num1_fields
} struct_2_fields;

int *structure;
if(case_1) {
  structure = malloc(4*sizeof(int));
} else if(case_2) {
  structure = malloc(6*sizeof(int));
} else {
 //something else
}
```

However since I would renominate the same enumerator, the compiler wouldn't work... is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is switching to c++ an option ?

Comment: Sorry... but no XD. Otherwise I would've used it.

Comment: You could extract the shared members into a third struct type, then use that to define your other structs: `typedef struct { struct_3 shared_fields; int c, d; } struct_1; ...` It's hard to say if that would solve your problem, though. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically substituting some similar structures with array, but I want to preserve the semantic of each field. So for example I could easily iterate through the struct fields, but when I need to treat each single field by semantic content I can rely on the enumeration, I could probably use macro definition for that purpose as well, but I don't want to abuse of macro definitions. The original structures are itself different, what is similar are some operations performed on them (some operations not all).

Comment: Say also I had more than 2 structures, merging common fields I guess could turn out into a mess...

Comment: Use a `struct` with `union`. Your approach invokes undefined behaviour and violates the _effective type_ (aka strict aliasing) rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OOP approach on C:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  // forward declaration for virtual function table
  struct vtable;

  // base class
  typedef struct {
    struct vtable* tbl_;
  } base;

  // virtual function table
  typedef struct vtable {
    void(*method_for_algorithm_1_)(base* object);
    void(*method_for_algorithm_2_)(base* object);
  } vtable;

  // algorithm 1 knowns only about base
  void algorithm_1(base* p[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      p[i]->tbl_->method_for_algorithm_1_(p[i]);
    }
  }

  // algorithm 2 knowns only about base
  void algorithm_2(base* p[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      p[i]->tbl_->method_for_algorithm_2_(p[i]);
    }
  }

  // struct1 is base
  typedef struct {
    base super_;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
  } struct1;

  // struct2 is base
  typedef struct {
    base super_;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
  } struct2;

  void struct1_method_for_algorithm1(base* object) {
    struct1* s1 = (struct1*)object;
    printf("struct1_method_for_algorithm1: %d %d %d\n", s1->a, s1->b, s1->c);
  }
  void struct1_method_for_algorithm2(base* object) {
    struct1* s1 = (struct1*)object;
    printf("struct1_method_for_algorithm2: %d %d %d\n", s1->a, s1->b, s1->c);
  }
  void struct2_method_for_algorithm1(base* object) {
    struct2* s2 = (struct2*)object;
    printf("struct2_method_for_algorithm1: %d %d %d %d %d\n", s2->a, s2->b, s2->c, s2->d, s2->e);
  }
  void struct2_method_for_algorithm2(base* object) {
    struct2* s2 = (struct2*)object;
    printf("struct2_method_for_algorithm2: %d %d %d %d %d\n", s2->a, s2->b, s2->c, s2->d, s2->e);
  }

  int main() {
    {
      vtable struct1vtable = {
        &struct1_method_for_algorithm1,
        &struct1_method_for_algorithm2
      };
      struct1 a[] = {
        { &struct1vtable, 10, 20, 30 },
        { &struct1vtable, 40, 50, 60 },
      };
      base* p[] = { &a[0], &a[1] };
      algorithm_1(p, 2);
      algorithm_2(p, 2);
    }
    {
      vtable struct2vtable = {
        &struct2_method_for_algorithm1,
        &struct2_method_for_algorithm2
      };
      struct2 a[] = {
        { &struct2vtable, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 },
        { &struct2vtable, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 },
      };
      base* p[] = { &a[0], &a[1] };
      algorithm_1(p, 2);
      algorithm_2(p, 2);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: This was actually one of the solutions I thought... I'm just scared is a bit complicated both to implement and to maintain.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there people who adopt this approach to C programming?

Comment: @user8469759 usally such approach is used when you need to maintain complex hierarchy with polymorthic behaviour on C. I am not sure that such approach is suitable for your, but I have to say that such solution is more maintanable than approaches with union and universal array.

Comment: Let me give it a go for some simple cases. Because I was looking for something like this.

Comment: I like this solution, it's more than I asked in this question but actually I think it covers my original problem. win32 Api also implement emulation like this when it register struct as classes.

Answer (score 0):

If `union` is an applicable solution for you

```
enum struct_types
{
    typ_struct_1,
    typ_struct_2
};

struct struct_1{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
 int d;
};

struct struct_2{
 int a;
 int b;
 int e;
 int f;
 int g;
 int h;
};

struct my_struct
{
    uint8_t struct_type;

    union u_members
    {
        struct struct_1 struct_1_typed;
        struct struct_2 struct_2_typed;
        int struct_1_raw[sizeof(struct struct_1)/sizeof(int)];
        int struct_2_raw[sizeof(struct struct_2)/sizeof(int)];
    }members;
};
```

Comment: The thing to be careful here is if you do `union merged *p = malloc(sizeof(*p))` you will allocate for `struct_2` even if you only use it for `struct_1`, wasting some space (no big deal for 2x`int`, but could be a problem). On the other hand, if you allocate `sizeof(struct_1)` you will segfault if you ever do `p->struct_2.h`.

Comment: @mtijanic Yes, sure in the same way if you `char *test = malloc(4)` and after `test[10] = 0;`. I mean that you have to `malloc`-ate the correct size otherwise undefine behavior. BTW it is not mandatory to use `malloc` with the proposed solution.

Comment: My concerns in this case are when I need to implement some special operations for struct_1 or struct_2, there's a reason why I'm spending my time understanding how can I work around the problem.

Comment: By the way, I don't think the memory allocation is actually a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could define the field offsets like this:

```
enum {
    /* common struct_1 and struct_2 fields */
    a,
    b,
    numcommon_fields,
    /* struct_1 fields */
    c = numcommon_fields,
    d,
    num1_fields,
    /* struct_2 fields */
    e = numcommon_fields,
    f,
    g,
    h,
    num2_fields
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as common field names share same index, you can go that way:

```
enum struct_fields {
    a = 0,
    b, c, d, num1_fields,
    e = 2, f, g, h, num2_fields
};

// if you need distinct names...
typedef enum struct_fields struct1_fields;
typedef enum struct_fields struct2_fields;
```

because if is legal to have more than one member of an enum to have a determinated value

Once that is done, you can safely do things like:

```
for (i=0; i<num2_fields; i++) {
    structure[i] = i*2;
}
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", structure[a], structure[b], structure[c], structure[d]);
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", structure[a], structure[b],
    structure[e], structure[f], structure[g], structure[h]);
```

to get as expected:

```
0 2 4 6
0 2 4 6 8 10
```

But never alias those arrays to your original structs because it would violate the strict aliasing rule

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, a `union` works well for what you want to do.  And it strictly conforms to the C Standard.

Per **6.5.2.3 Structure and union members**, paragraph 6 of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **Constraints**
>
> ...
>
> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions:
>   if a union contains several  structures  that  share  a  common 
>   initial  sequence  (see  below),  and  if  the  union object 
>   currently  contains  one  of  these  structures,  it  is  permitted 
>   to  inspect  the  common initial part of any of them anywhere that a
>   declaration of the completed type of the union is  visible.   Two 
>   structures  share  a common  initial  sequence if  corresponding 
>   members have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths)
>   for a sequence of one or more initial members.

For example, the X Windows `XEvent` union, [defined in `X11/Xlib.h`](http://opensource.apple.com//source/tcl/tcl-87/tk/tk/xlib/X11/Xlib.h):

```
/*
 * this union is defined so Xlib can always use the same sized
 * event structure internally, to avoid memory fragmentation.
 */
typedef union _XEvent {
    int type;       /* must not be changed; first element */
    XAnyEvent xany;
    XKeyEvent xkey;
    XButtonEvent xbutton;
    XMotionEvent xmotion;
    XCrossingEvent xcrossing;
    XFocusChangeEvent xfocus;
    XExposeEvent xexpose;
    XGraphicsExposeEvent xgraphicsexpose;
    XNoExposeEvent xnoexpose;
    XVisibilityEvent xvisibility;
    XCreateWindowEvent xcreatewindow;
    XDestroyWindowEvent xdestroywindow;
    XUnmapEvent xunmap;
    XMapEvent xmap;
    XMapRequestEvent xmaprequest;
    XReparentEvent xreparent;
    XConfigureEvent xconfigure;
    XGravityEvent xgravity;
    XResizeRequestEvent xresizerequest;
    XConfigureRequestEvent xconfigurerequest;
    XCirculateEvent xcirculate;
    XCirculateRequestEvent xcirculaterequest;
    XPropertyEvent xproperty;
    XSelectionClearEvent xselectionclear;
    XSelectionRequestEvent xselectionrequest;
    XSelectionEvent xselection;
    XColormapEvent xcolormap;
    XClientMessageEvent xclient;
    XMappingEvent xmapping;
    XErrorEvent xerror;
    XKeymapEvent xkeymap;
    long pad[24];
} XEvent;
```

All the various types of XEvent start with `int type`, for example:

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    unsigned long serial;   /* # of last request processed by server */
    Bool send_event;    /* true if this came from a SendEvent request */
    Display *display;   /* Display the event was read from */
    Window window;
    int width, height;
} XResizeRequestEvent;
```

or

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    unsigned long serial;   /* # of last request processed by server */
    Bool send_event;    /* true if this came from a SendEvent request */
    Display *display;   /* Display the event was read from */
    Window event;
    Window window;
    Bool override_redirect; /* boolean, is override set... */
} XMapEvent;
```

In fact, the commonality goes well beyond the `int type` first field for most `XEvent` types.  Most of the event types start with the following fields from `XAnyEvent`:

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    unsigned long serial;   /* # of last request processed by server */
    Bool send_event;    /* true if this came from a SendEvent request */
    Display *display;/* Display the event was read from */
    Window window;  /* window on which event was requested in event mask */
} XAnyEvent;
```